# Laravel relationship count()

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I want to get a total user transaction (specific user) with relationship. 
I've done it but i'm curious is my way is good approach.

```
//User Model
public function Transaction()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Transaction::class);
}

//Merchant Model

public function Transaction()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Transaction::class);
}

public function countTransaction()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Transaction::class)
        ->where('user_id', Request::get('user_id'))
        ->groupBy('merchant_id');
}

public function getCountTransactionAttribute()
{
    if ($this->relationLoaded('countTransaction'))
        $this->load('countTransaction');

    $related = $this->getRelation('countTransaction');

    return ($related) ? (int)$related->total_transaction : 0;
}

//controller

$merchant = Merchant::with('countTransaction')->get();
```

What make me curious is part inside `countTransaction`. I put `where where('user_id', Request::get('user_id'))` directly inside the model.

is it good approach or any other way to get specific way?

expected result:

```
"merchant:"{
    "name": "example"
    "username" : "example"
    "transactions": {
        "count_transactions: "4" //4 came from a specific user.
    }
}
```

I need to get the merchant data with the transaction count for specific user. This query is based on logged in user. so when a `user` access merchant page, they can see their transaction count for that merchant.

Thanks.

Comment: Is `Merchant` your user? Or do you have an actual `User` model?

Comment: I have an actual user. 3 table. users, merchants, and transactions

Comment: So a `User` also `hasMany` transactions?

Comment: Yes. User has many transactions

Comment: And do you simply want to count the # of transactions for a specific user? I'm trying to understand how `Merchant` plays into this.

Comment: yes. so from `Merchant` i want to count a specific `user` transaction.

Comment: Last question: what do you want your returned collection to look like?

Comment: @tptcat i've update my question with expected result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99655/discussion-between-tptcat-and-sstarlight).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really want to keep request data outside of your models (instead opting to pass it in). I'm also a little confused about why you have both a 'hasOne' for transactions, and a 'hasMany' for transactions within the merchant model.

I would probably approach the problem more like the below (untested, but along these lines). Again I'm not fully sure I understand what you need, but along these lines

```
    // Merchant Model
    public function transactions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Transaction::class);
    }

    public function countTransactionsByUser($userId)
    {
        return $this
                ->transactions()
                ->where('user_id', $userId)
                ->get()
                ->pluck('total_transaction')
                ->sum();
    }

    // Controller

    $userId = request()->get('user_id');

    // ::all() or however you want to reduce 
    // down the Merchant collection
    //
    $merchants = Merchant::all()->map(function($item, $key) {
        $_item = $item->getAttributes();
        $_item['transactions'] = [
            'count_transactions' => $item->countTransactionsByUser($userId);
        ];
        return $_item;
    });

    // Single total
    // Find merchant 2, and then get the total transactions 
    // for user 2
    //
    $singleTotal = Merchant::find(2)
        ->countTransactionsByUser($userId);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying to understand my question.

The reason i make 2 transactions is: countTransaction will return one value not array. that's why i make it `hasOne` instead of using `hasMany`.

I've tried your solution using `$singleTotal` it's great but I can't get merchant result. Thanks

Comment: Could you post the result you did get?

Comment: result: `[10]`. I've update my question hope can be more understandable.  `This query is based on logged in user. so when a user access merchant page, they can see their transaction count for that merchant.`

Comment: What is the output of the first command (the map one)? The intended output of the second, would be a single number (in this case 10)

Comment: `[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "merchant 1",
     "transactions": [10]
   }
   {
      
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Merchant 2",
     "transactions": [3]
   }
]`

Comment: I've updated the answer to include the extra key - it is curious that the value is wrapped as an array when array_sum should return a number, not an array

Comment: sorry my bad. if I put `array_sum` it will return error that's why i tried to remove it. the error is `"Array_sum() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given"`

Comment: I make it working with your way. I change the count user point function become `return $this->userPoint()->where('user_id', $userId)->get()->pluck('point_earned')->sum();` and now it's working and looks better to read the code. Thanks!!

Comment: Would you mind updating my answer, or post a gist of the changes you made so anyone hitting the site in future knows the correct approach